# How can I add a degree sign to a string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode

I'm writing in Objective-C.
How can I add a degree sign to a string? I know its unicode: `00B0` and UTF8: `C2 B0`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the string literal: `\u00B0`. For Unicode characters, it will always be "\u" followed by the character code.

```
NSString *temperature = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"65%@", @"\u00B0"];
```

Comment: How can we do this in IB?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş: You should just be able to paste ° into the field.

Answer (score 18):

This is how you would do it using Swift:

```
var temperature = "65\u{00B0}" // degree symbol
```

Answer (score 5):

Just found this very helpful answer but it can even be abbreviated to the following (self explanatory):

```
NSString *temperature = @"65\u00B0";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"80\u00b0c"];
    [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-light" size:40.0]
                                      , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @22} range:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
    //asign this as a 
examplelabel.attributedtext = attributedString;
```