# Issue with degree celsius symbol - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, csv, utf-8

I have a CSV creation project, I created it and works fine, but one problem when it opens; it shows degree celsius symbol as below;

[image]

and my code looks like this;

```
 writeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",tempString,@"°c"];

 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:csvFilePath contents:[writeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
```

I added '°' symbol using cmd+shift+8, it looks fine in Xcode but problem arises when it opens in spreadsheet manipulating applications, I need your help...

Comment: Try NSISOLatin1StringEncoding or, NSASCIIStringEncoding while writing..

Comment: "Spreadsheet opening applications"??  Are they using the correct encoding?  Windows vs. Mac by any chance?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663064/how-can-i-add-a-degree-sign-to-a-string

Comment: @iphonic: thanks man!!! worked NSISOLatin1Encoding for me!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NSISOLatin1StringEncoding or NSASCIIStringEncoding while it writing to csv. Below code worked for me.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:csvFilePath contents:[writeString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
```

(i got the solution from the comments on my question, i think this may help some others)